# Call same method signature with different implementations

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns

Given:
I have two different projects legacy A and nextGen B.
There is the third project C which is shared between A and B.

Objective:
I have to do an averageCalculation() in the third project C. But the implementation is different for the projects A and B. Using the same method signature but different implementations, how do I create a design? Note: the project A and B should just call averageCalulation() the same method signature.

Project C

```
Interface I {
averageCalculation();
}

Class CClass implements I{
?<averageCalculation()-for A>
?<averageCalculation()- for B>
}
```

Project A

```
{
I i1 = new CClass();
i1.averageCalculation();
}
```

Project B

```
{
I i2 = new CClass();
i2.averageCalculation();
}
```

Is the above approach correct? if so how would i create two implementations of averageCalculation() in CClass?

Comment: Does CClass implement interface I.  What would the signature of the two methods be ? Question needs a bit more clarity

Comment: @Moh123 Yes. Whatever you have said is right. I have made edits to the question.

Comment: if I understand your project well, so why do you not do this:  class A implements I { averageCalculation()} class B implements I { averageCalculation()}  class CClass{ I i = new A(); I i1 = new B()}

Comment: Because averageCalculation() is a method called in C. There are other set of methods which does the same operations as averageCalculation() in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two different classes that implement your interface, and use a different class in each project:

Project C

```
interface I {
averageCalculation();
}

class CClassForA implements I{
    averageCalculation(){...} // for A
}

class CClassForB implements I{
    averageCalculation(){...} // for B
}
```

Project A

```
{
I i1 = new CClassForA();
i1.averageCalculation();
}
```

Project B

```
{
I i2 = new CClassForB();
i2.averageCalculation();
}
```

Comment: What if I am calling avarage calculation from a different method in from Project C? doCalculate(){averageCalculation()};?

Comment: @Arun: `averageCalculation` represents a "reason to change", so SOLID principles dictate that it should be in a separate class from your other methods, which aren't changing. Any class that calls `averageCalculation()` should require an `I` as either a method parameter or a constructor parameter, and call `averageCalculation()` on that. Project C: `doCalculate(I i) { i.averageCalculation(); }` Project A: `doCalculate(new CClassForA())`.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just a contract for classes that implement it to define. If a class needs two different implementations of a single method in an interface then you should consider redesigning your project

Why do you need CClass ? You can have a class in Project A implement I and another class in Project B doing the same.

**EDIT :** the compiler will not let you have two different implementations of the method with the same signature. You do have an option to overload it if that is what you want

```
public interface SomeInter 
{
   public void doSomething();
}


public class ImplClass implements SomeInter
{

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void doSomething(String abc) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: in CClass, I have a bunch of other methods which call averageCalculation based on some conditions.

A->C->CClass->someMethod()->If x > 50 do averageCalulation() else something else...

B->C->CClass->someMethod()->If x > 50 do averageCalulation() else something else...

Comment: does this make sense or do you need further clarification

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem entirely but here is a solution. You can't change the legacy projects but you want to A and B to conform to some Interface I. You can do this by wrapping A and B in something that does conform to I and implement I with A and B's respective implementations.

```
public class Problem {

    public static class A{
        public int foo(){
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static class B{
        public int foo(){
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public interface TheFoo{
        public int foo();
    }

    public static class AWrapper extends A implements TheFoo{
        public int foo(){
            return super.foo();
        }
    }

    public static class BWrapper extends B implements TheFoo{
        public int foo(){
            return super.foo();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //TheFoo[] myFoos = new TheFoo[]{new A(), new B()}; Won't work
        TheFoo[] myFoos = new TheFoo[]{new AWrapper(), new BWrapper()};
        for(TheFoo curFoo : myFoos){
            System.out.println(curFoo.foo());
        }
    }   
}
```